# Привязка по baseline в ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

У меня есть следующий layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/play_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:button="@drawable/ic_play_btn"
        android:buttonTint="@color/green"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:checked="true" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/audio_player_thumb"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/play_btn"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/playback_position"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:progress="25"
        tools:secondaryProgress="75" />

        ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

В этом случае всё выглядит так, как мне нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я хочу сделать то же самое с помощью привязки по baseline, т.е. я заменяю

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

у первого виджета (`CheckBox`-а) на

```
app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/seekbar"
```

но в этом случае `CheckBox` улетает вверх:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно расположить `CheckBox` на одной линии с `SeekBar`, используя `app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf`? Или же это невозможно, потому что baseline может быть только у `TextView`?

Comment: А зачем вы вообще хотите baseLine использовать? Как она поможет решить вашу задачу?